# How to detect when Material radio-button or group lost focus?

Tags: angular, angular-material

That's the question, can't detect it. I've tried:

```
<mat-radio-button [value]="value" (blur)="onBlur($event)">
```

but in vain. I understand that blur event should have only those elements that can be focused, and material button deep inside have input element. So, is there simple solution without complicated workarounds?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event binding directly `(focusout)` on `mat-radio-group` or `mat-radio-button`.
HTML Code:

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" (focusout)="outOfFocus()">
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

TS Code:

```
outOfFocus(){
 console.log("You reached out of focus")
}
```

Comment: Indeed, focusout can bubble, blur can't, good idea!